# Can CNF be converted to DNF using double negation?

Tags: logic

Is it possible to convert a formula in conjunctive normal form (CNF) to disjunctive normal form (DNF) using double negation?

For example, given the following formula in CNF:

```
(¬A ∧ B ∧ ¬C) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ B ∧ C)
¬¬((¬A ∧ B ∧ ¬C) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ B ∧ C))
¬((A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (¬A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ ¬C))
```

I am not sure if it is still a valid DNF.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: And with double negation it should also work the other way too, from DNF to CNF. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The first formula that you give is not in CNF.  Rather, it is in DNF.  If you start with a formula in CNF, you can convert it to DNF by using Demorgan's law twice.

Comment: Oh yes, my error in the example, I go from DNF to CNF. But my question was mainly about the double negation, which as far as I understand can be used to go from DNF to CNF and from CNF to DNF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first of your given expressions is actually allready in DNF. Using double negation you will get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha:&(\lnot A\land B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land \lnot B \land C) \lor (A \land B \land C) \\
\equiv& \lnot(\lnot ((\lnot A\land B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land \lnot B \land C) \lor (A \land B \land C))) \\
\equiv& \lnot((A \lor \lnot B \lor C) \land (\lnot A \lor B \lor \lnot C) \land (\lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C)) && (1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Drawing a truth table might help understanding what this means. Let $\alpha = \alpha_1 \lor \alpha_2 \lor \alpha_3$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc|cl}
A & B & C & \alpha \\
\hline
T & T & T & \boxed{T} & \Rightarrow \alpha_1: A \land B \land C \\
T & T & F & F & \Rightarrow \hat\alpha_1: A \land B \land \lnot C \\
T & F & T & \boxed{T} & \Rightarrow \alpha_2: A \land \lnot B \land C\\
T & F & F & F & \Rightarrow \hat\alpha_2: A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C \\
F & T & T & F & \Rightarrow \hat\alpha_3: \lnot A \land B \land C \\
F & T & F & \boxed{T} & \Rightarrow \alpha_3: \lnot A \land B \land \lnot C \\
F & F & T & F & \Rightarrow \hat\alpha_4: \lnot A \land \lnot B \land C \\
F & F & F & F & \Rightarrow \hat\alpha_5: \lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C
\end{array}
$$
Lets take the DNF for $\lnot\alpha = \hat\alpha_1 \lor \hat\alpha_2 \lor \hat\alpha_3 \lor \hat\alpha_4 \lor \hat\alpha_5$

$$
\lnot\alpha : (A \land B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A \land B \land C) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land C) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C)
$$

Inverting $\lnot\alpha$ will result in the CNF of $\alpha$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha \equiv& \lnot(\lnot\alpha) \\
\equiv& \qquad\;\;\; \lnot((A \land B \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A \land B \land C) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land C) \\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C)) \\
\equiv& \lnot(A \land B \land \lnot C) \land \lnot(A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \land \lnot(\lnot A \land B \land C) \land \lnot(\lnot A \land \lnot B \land C) \land \lnot(\lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \\
\equiv& (\lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor C) \land (\lnot A \lor B \lor C) \land (A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C) \land (A \lor B \lor \lnot C) \land (A \lor B \lor C)
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice that this is still equivalent to $(1)$. The definition of CNF/DNF requires that the not operator has to precede a propositional variable or a predicate symbol. This requirement is not fulfilled by $(1)$.

So it is possible to convert DNF to CNF using double negation and vice versa but make sure to be aware what exactly you are negating.